# Vue JS - Set start year and end year dropdown conditionally

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dropdown, vuejs3

I'm currently experiencing a hard time coming up with the appropriate logic to implement a start - end year in vue. Both the start and end year are represented by two seperate dropdowns. The functionality of them both work as they should, however my issue lies within conditionally setting the end year based on what was set as the start year and vice versa. Meaning that if the start year '2016' was selected from the dropdown, the end year dropdown would only show values between 2016 and 2021.

Setyear.vue

```html
<div class="detail-input start-end-dates">
     <div class="year-picker">
          <YearPicker :placeholder="'Voeg datum toe'"
                :select-name="'startYear'"
                :title="'Startdatum'"
                :selected="educationInfo.startYear"
                :earliest-date="currentYear - 50"
                :latest-date="endYear"
                :callback="setStartYear"/>
      </div>

      <div class="year-picker">
           <YearPicker :placeholder="'Voeg datum toe'"
                       :select-name="'endYear'"
                       :title="'Einddatum'"
                       :selected="educationInfo.endYear"
                       :earliest-date="startYear ? startYear : currentYear - 50" // this section doesn't really work as although startYear is updated, it only returns the initial value of start year which is null
                       :latest-date="currentYear + 50"
                       :callback="setEndYear"/>
     </div>
</div>

<script>
import YearPicker from "@/components/elements/YearPicker";
import {ref, computed, watch} from "@vue/composition-api";

export default {
  name: "Setyear",
  components: {YearPicker},
  props: {
    educationInfo: {
      type: Object,
      required: false
    }
  },
  setup(props, {emit}) {
    const currentYear = ref(0);
    setCurrentYear();

    function setCurrentYear() {
      currentYear.value = new Date().getFullYear();
    }

    const startYear = ref(props.educationInfo.startYear ? props.educationInfo.startYear : null);

    function setStartYear(year) {
      startYear.value = year;
    }

    const endYear = ref(props.educationInfo.endYear ? props.educationInfo.endYear : null);

    function setEndYear(year) {
      endYear.value = year;
    }

    return {
      startYear,
      endYear,
      currentYear,
      setStartYear,
      setEndYear,
    }
  },
}
```

YearPicker.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h3 class="form-input-title">{{ title }}</h3>
    <select name="startYear" id="startYear" :value="selected" class="form-input" @change="executeCallback">
      <option></option>
      <option v-for="year in validYears" :key="year" :value="year">{{year}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {ref, onBeforeMount, watch, computed} from "@vue/composition-api";

export default {
  name: "YearPicker",
  props: {
    title: {type: String},
    callback: {type: Function},
    selected: {type: [String, Number]},
    earliestDate: {type: [Number, String],},
    latestDate: {type: [Number, String]}
  },
  setup(props) {
    onBeforeMount(calculateDateRange)

    watch(() => props.earliestDate, (newValue, prevValue) => {
      calculateDateRange();
    });
    // If there is a new value passed from the parent, the dropdown should display that new value.
    watch(() => props.latestDate, (newValue, prevValue) => {
      calculateDateRange()
    });

    function executeCallback(event) {
      props.callback(event.target.value);
    }

    const validYears = ref([])
    function calculateDateRange () {
      for(let year = props.latestDate; year >= props.earliestDate; year--){
        validYears.value.push(year)
      }
    }

    return {
      validYears,
      executeCallback,
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I don't believe the year picker component needs to be amended which is why I did not show the code. It only loops over the years to display the available options. My issue is related to coming up with a solid logical solution that helps me limit the years based on what was selected in either dropdown. I'd appreciate your suggestions!

Comment: I'm not seeing issues in the code here. The question is about getting a solid logical solution for limiting the years, but you didn't include the Yearpicker that currently contains the existing logic?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a computed value to set the 'earliest date' variable:

```
computed: {
   earliestDate() {
       if (this.startYear) {
            return this.startYear
       }
       return currentYear - 50
    }
}
```

Then you could hook that value into your component like:
`:earliest-date = {{ earliestDate() }}`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `YearPicker` uses a computed property to populate the dropdown based on the `earliestDate` and `latestDate` props so that the years are automatically recalculated when the props change:

```js
// YearPicker.vue
import { computed } from '@vue/composition-api'

export default {
  setup(props) {
    function executeCallback(event) {
      props.callback(event.target.value);
    }

    const validYears = computed(() => {
      const years = []
      for (let year = props.latestDate; year >= props.earliestDate; year--) {
        years.push(year)
      }
      return years.length ? years : ([props.latestDate || props.earliestDate])
    })

    return {
      validYears,
      executeCallback,
    }
  }
}
```

Then in `SetYear`, bind `startYear` and `endYear` to the first and second `YearPicker`s' `selected` prop, respectively:

```html
// SetYear.vue
<div class="year-picker">
    <YearPicker ...
                :selected="startYear"
                :earliest-date="currentYear - 50"
                :latest-date="endYear"
                :callback="setStartYear"/>
</div>

<div class="year-picker">
    <YearPicker ...
                :selected="endYear"
                :earliest-date="startYear ? startYear : currentYear - 50"
                :latest-date="currentYear + 50"
                :callback="setEndYear"/>
</div>
```

Assuming that `YearPicker` invokes the `callback` property whenever the input changes value, these bindings in `SetYear` should automatically update the `YearPicker`'s start and end dates.

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-interdependent-date-pickers-98gdae?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FYearPicker.vue)

Comment: I believe this is what I'm after. But I realised that the YearPicker component is fundamental to solving this issue. I'm still a bit confused as to how I can replicate this logic to my YearPicker component. I got close but I was experiencing some problems. I edited my message by exposing the yeaPicker component to offer some more context. I'd really appreciate if you could have another look as I feel really close with this.

Comment: @thelandog Updated answer to show the computed prop, using Composition API